# How to combine two files by matching two parameters with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file `A.txt` (sep = `\t` ):

```
Cycle   Well    Value   Target
1   A1  5.07368111264623    EC
1   A1  3.06982862746599    FT
1   A1  2.46545646544623    EC
```

And a second file `B.txt` (sep = `\t`, **first column is empty**):

```
    Well    Fluor   Target  Content Sample
    A1  Cy5 EC  Unkn-01 2060563935
    A1  Cy5 FT  Unkn-09 2156515156
```

I want to add the column `Content` from `B.txt` in `A.txt` if **both** `Well` and `Target` are the same data from the two files, and output the result to `C.txt` (sep = `\t`):

```
Cycle   Well    Value   Target  Content
1   A1  5.07368111264623    EC  Unkn-01
1   A1  3.06982862746599    FT  Unkn-09
1   A1  2.46545646544623    EC  Unkn-01
```

I try stuff like:

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{if (a[$2]) {a[$2]=a[$2] "\t" $7} else {a[$2]=$7}} NR>FNR{split($0,f,"\t"); if (a[f[4]]) $0=$0 "\t" a[f[4]]; print}'
```

But it didn't work. Any Idea how to do that?

Precision :

- In the first file used as template (A.txt), mutiple lign with the same Well & Target are present.
- In B.txt, there are only one line with the same Well/target combination.
- It is not possible to not have matching pattern in file A from file B.

Comment: Are the lines to merge on the same position in both files (i.e. merge line 1 of `A.txt` with line 1 of `B.txt`, if both fields match, and so on for the other lines), or can they be at different positions in the respective files? What to do if there is no match for a specific line: Ignore it or output an incomplete line to `C.txt`?

Comment: @AdminBee No the line are note in the same position; there are in my example but not in the real data set that are thousand of lines. In my mind , the awk command screen the first file and add the correspondent "Content" info ( i.e the first file is the template)

Comment: @nstatam Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. Is it guaranteed that there is exactly one line with any combination of Well and Target in both files? Or is it possible that no matching line exists in one of the files? Or more than one line for the same combination?

Comment: @Bodo I edit my question at the end for more precision

Comment: @nstatam I suggest to show an example that actually contains multiple lines with the same combination of Well and Target and show the expected output matching the input. This might answer some of the following questions. You specified that file `A.txt` can contain multiple lines with the same Well/Target combination. What about `B.txt`? Assuming there are two lines in `A.txt` with Well/Target `A1`/ `EC`, should all these lines be printed with the corresponding data from `B.txt`?

Comment: @Badoo I re-edit with a more precise example and add some precision

Comment: You should add the file arguments  to your `awk` command because the order is important. `$7`must be wrong as the input files have only 4 or 6 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution using **GNU awk** or **POSIX awk**

**Edit:** As [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) wrote in his comment, the original answer was wrong about what is supported by GNU `awk` only. (The wording in the GNU documentation vs. the POSIX documentation is a bit confusing.)

What the GNU `awk` documentation calls [Multidimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html) is supported by POSIX compatible `awk`. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/awk.html and search for "multi-dimensional" or `SUBSEP`. These arrays are in fact one-dimensional.

GNU `awk` also supports [Arrays of Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) which are real multi-dimensional arrays.

This version of the command requires GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR == FNR { a[$2][$4] = $5; next } { print $0, a[$2][$4] }' B.txt A.txt > C.txt
```

The POSIX compatible variant (*), which should work with any `awk` is

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR == FNR { a[$2,$4] = $5; next } { print $0, a[$2,$4] }' B.txt A.txt > C.txt
```

Both print

```
Cycle   Well    Value   Target 
1   A1  5.07368111264623    EC Unkn-01
1   A1  3.06982862746599    FT Unkn-09
1   A1  2.46545646544623    EC Unkn-01
```

The data from file `B.txt` is saved into array `a` because according to the question the key Well/Target is unique in this file. Then this data is appended to data from file `A.txt`.

The field separator must be explicitly specified. Otherwise `awk` would ignore empty columns/values.

This solution uses fixed column numbers to identify the columns to match or to print.

**Edit:** The following solution solution which explicitly combines the index expressions with `\t` as separator has no advantage compared to the POSIX compatible solution (*) shown above.

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR == FNR { a[$2 "\t" $4] = $5; next } { print $0, a[$2 "\t" $4] }' B.txt A.txt > C.txt
```

This is equivalent to setting `SUBSEP = "\t"` and using the syntax `a[$2, $4]`.

---

Second solution using **q**

The tool q can be used to perform database like queries on CSV files.

See http://harelba.github.io/q/ or https://github.com/harelba/q

This solution has a problem with the empty column title in `B.txt`. As a workaround I added a title `Empty` to the heading row of this file.

So I use these files:

`A.txt`

```
Cycle   Well    Value   Target
1   A1  5.07368111264623    EC
1   A1  3.06982862746599    FT
1   A1  2.46545646544623    EC
```

`B.txt`

```
Empty   Well    Fluor   Target  Content Sample
    A1  Cy5 EC  Unkn-01 2060563935
    A1  Cy5 FT  Unkn-09 2156515156
```

The command

```
q -H -t "select a.Cycle,a.Well,a.Value,a.Target,b.Content from A.txt as a inner join B.txt as b on a.Well=b.Well and a.Target=b.Target"
```

prints

```
1   A1  5.07368111264623    EC  Unkn-01
1   A1  3.06982862746599    FT  Unkn-09
1   A1  2.46545646544623    EC  Unkn-01
```

To print the header you can add a `printf` or `echo` command.

```
printf "Cycle\tWell\tValue\tTarget\tContent\n" > C.txt
q -H -t "select a.Cycle,a.Well,a.Value,a.Target,b.Content from A.txt as a inner join B.txt as b on a.Well=b.Well and a.Target=b.Target" >> C.txt
```

To automate the modification of file `B.txt` you can use

```
printf "Empty" > B1.txt
cat B.txt >> B1.txt
printf "Cycle\tWell\tValue\tTarget\tContent\n" > C.txt
q -H -t "select a.Cycle,a.Well,a.Value,a.Target,b.Content from A.txt as a inner join B1.txt as b on a.Well=b.Well and a.Target=b.Target" >> C.txt
```

This solution used named columns from the header row to identify the columns to match or to print.

Comment: You're not using two-dimensional arrays, you're using pseudo-two-dimensional arrays (which are actually still one-dimensional) and those are supported by every awk. Writing `a[$2,$4]` is just shorthand for writing `a[$2 SUBSEP $4]` where `SUBSEP` is a builtin variable set to a control character that's unlikely to appear in your input. In your code there is no functional difference between `a[$2,$4]` and `a[$2 "\t" $4]` (which is identical to `SUBSEP="\t"; a[$2,$4]`) unless the input can contain SUBSEP or a tab. Two-dimensional array syntax (as supported by gawk) would look like `a[$2][$4]`

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for the clarification. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have GNU `awk` for two-dimensional arrays, the following program will do the task:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR&&FNR>1{map[$2][$4]=$5}\
            NR>FNR{if (FNR==1) {$5="Content"} else {$5=map[$2][$4]}} NR>FNR' B.txt A.txt > C.txt
```

This will first process `B.txt` to create a mapping of "Content" values to a specific "Well" and "Target" combination. When processing `A.txt` afterwards (indicated by `FNR`, the per-file line-counter now being smaller than `NR`, the global line-counter), the program looks for the specific combination of "Well" and "Target" on the current line and substitutes the corresponding "Content" value from the map created earlier. It prints output only then processing the second file (the "stray" `NR>FNR` condition).

Comment: +1 Slightly more complete than the accepted solution, although imho your 2nd `NR>FNR` at the end is as awkward (pun intended) as it is necessary to print things out.

Comment: @Cbhihe True. Although I usually try to make the code readable rather than "golfed", writing it this way is shorter than having `next` in the first and `print` in the second rule ;)

Comment: Mmmh...I'm with you for not golfing in this forum, but with `next` in 1st rule's set of braces, you could do away with `NR>FNR` in the 2nd rule, AND replace the last occurrence of  `NR>FNR` with `{print}`.  This was exactly what I was thinking, but decided not to mention it earlier, because style is... style. It's hard to argue against it, especially if the answer is flawless. ;-)

Comment: @Cbhihe True, that is indeed a way to make it more efficient. I will keep it in mind for future answers :)